# Akka Streams: validation of elements being streamed

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm new to Akka Streams and I'm wondering how to implement some kind of mid-stream validation. Example:

```
FileIO
  .fromPath(file)
  .via(Framing.delimiter(...)
  .map(_.utf8String)
  .map(_.split("\t", -1))
  .validate(arr => arr.length == 10) // or similar
  ...
```

I assumed that this scenario is so common that there must be a predefined functionality for validating a stream on the fly. However, I wasn't able to find anything about it. Am I on the wrong tracks here and validation is something that should not be done *this way* in Akka Streams?

In my particular scenario, I'm processing a file line by line. If only one single line is invalid, it does not make sense to continue and the processing should be aborted.

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want it continue processing other lines. Or does an invalid line shutdown the stream.

Comment: @Stephen As I wrote above, continuing does not make sense in case of any validation error and I want to abort the processing of the stream in a clean way.

Comment: You might like the kill switches discussed here http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-dynamic.html

Comment: What about values that pass validation before stream fails? Should it be taken in account or dropped?

Comment: @Zernike already processed elements can be ignored and are no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably create a type to represent the constraints, then you can do the assertions when creating instances of that type, as well as know downstream which constraints have been applied.

Example:

```
object LineItem {
  // Makes it possible to provide the validation before allocating the item
  def apply(string: String): LineItem = {
    require(string.length == 10)
    new LineItem(string) // Call the companion-accessible constructor
  }
}
// private[LineItem] makes sure that `new` only works from companion object
final case class LineItem private[LineItem](string: String)
```

Comment: Could you provide a simple toy example? What I'm doing at the moment is to map each line (meaning each `Array[String]`) to a `LineItem` case class type which performs `require` in its constructor, but I guess that's not what you meant.

Comment: @ceran Good question, I've elaborated with an explanation of what I meant (which does indeed sound somewhat like what you're already doing)

Comment: In addition to Viktor's suggestion, if one wants to log multiple failures at one go (which was not the case here), Akka Streams provides ways to catch such exceptions, log, and recover.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Stephen that `takeWhile` is what you need. You can use it with the `inclusive` flag set to true if you want the failing elements to be passed downstream.

Also, if you want to make your stream the most expressive, you can have the validation flow producing `Either[ValidationError, String]`.

The example below is a bit clunky, I would prefer to use the graphDSL and `partition`, but hopefully you get the idea.

```
  val errorSink: Sink[TooManyElements, _] = ???
  val sink: Sink[Array[String], _] = ???

  FileIO
    .fromPath(file)
    .via(Framing.delimiter(...))
    .map(_.utf8String.split("\t", -1))
    .map{
      case arr if arr.length > 10 ⇒ Left(TooManyElements(arr.length))
      case arr                    ⇒ Right(arr)
    }
    .takeWhile(_.isRight, inclusive = true)
    .alsoTo(Flow[Either[TooManyElements, Array[String]]].filter(_.isLeft).to(errorSink)
    .filter(_.isRight)
    .to(sink)
```

Comment: In the end, isn't the outcome roughly the same as just using `filter` on the stream (albeit being more expressive of course)? This is what I did before, but what I want to do is not to divide into "good and bad" but to immediately shut down the stream in case of a validation problem.

Comment: No. Using `filter`, only valid lines passes downstream, so you cannot print out, which line was wrong or how many elements does it have. The `errorSink` in this answer gets the first problematic line, so it can print the details about it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.takeWhile`. This will process all elements before the invalid item, and not process any items after it.

```
FileIO
  .fromPath(file)
  .via(Framing.delimiter(...)
  .map(_.utf8String)
  .map(_.split("\t", -1))
  .takeWhile(arr => arr.length == 10)
  ...
```

Comment: I like it for its simplicitly. But if I'm not wrong, there is no way to find out if a validation error occured since `takeWhile`has no error semantics. The total amount of elements is not known beforehand, so I can't compare it to the amount of elements that succesfully passed `takeWhile` .